# Does PVST allow to bridge two VLANs?

Tags: cisco, switch, vlan, spanning-tree

I am having a Switch

> Cisco IOS Software, C2960 Software (C2960-LANBASEK9-M), Version
>   12.2(50)SE4, RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc1)

I have interface FastEthernet0/1 up to interface FastEthernet0/48 are configured as switchport access vlan , switchport mode access, no cdp enable.

and

> spanning-tree mode pvst spanning-tree extend system-id

My question is, whether it is possible to bridge two ports without one of the port goes into Blocking State? I mean why should it when it's a PER vlan spanning-tree.

Answer (score 0):

No, not in the configuration you described.  One port will be in a **BLK** (blocking) state.

---

`spanning-tree mode pvst` will globally enable **PVST**.  `spanning-tree extend system-id` affects how the *Bridge IDs* are created.  More details about the `spanning-tree extend system-id` command can be found [here](https://learningnetwork.cisco.com/thread/21718).

If only a single VLAN exists, any bridge between any two ports will cause a **bridging loop**.  **BPDUs** will be detected and the port will change to a blocking state.

Both ports will be in a **FWD** (forwarding) state if:

- Port are in two different VLANs.  Bad things can happen as two different VLANs are bridged.
- `spanning-tree bpdufilter enable` is configured at the interface or globally configured.  This will create a **bridging loop** and subsequently cause a [Broadcast Storm](http://www.professormesser.com/network-plus/n10-006/troubleshooting-broadcast-storms-and-switching-loops/) (<--*very bad*).

Note that enabling **BPDU Filters** by itself is typically very dangerous to stability of the network.

The Cisco [12.2SX Software Configuration Guide](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/lan/catalyst6500/ios/12-2SX/configuration/guide/book/spantree.html) provides detailed guidance on **STP** (Spanning Tree Protocol) and its optional features such as **BPDU Filtering**.